# Cannot get access_token from LinkedIn api

Tags: ruby, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I'm using [linkedin-oauth2 gem](https://github.com/emorikawa/linkedin-oauth2) for LinkedIn api access.
I'm doing exactly what is need to be done in order to get access_token

```
# create linkedin application client
client = LinkedIn::Client.new('your_client_id', 'your_client_secret')

# get authorize url
authorize_url = client.authorize_url

# go to this url and fetch api_code from the url
client.request_access_token(code, redirect_uri: "http://localhost")
```

I have an error:

> LinkedIn::Errors::UnauthorizedError: missing required parameters,
>   includes an invalid parameter value, parameter more then once. :
>   Unable to retrieve access token : appId or redirect uri does not match
>   authorization code or authorization code expired

Comment: where is your `code`? auth_code aka code. (Check in url you were directed to after a successful auth). Use this auth code

Comment: also `client.request_access_token("<auth_code from last step>")` it should have only one argument but you also give `redirect_uri`

Comment: code it taken from the response of  client.authorize_url  of course 'your_client_id', 'your_client_secret' are also real from my application registered in linkedin.

Comment: I tried also client.request_access_token("<auth_code from last step>")

Comment: same error?..........